# Playing Sound in Putty during tail Option

Tags: linux, bash

My requirement is to play an alert (Play Sound) in putty if any Exception occurs in the Application , so for this purpose i have tried the below way

```
tail -f flex.log | grep "Exception" --color paplay alert.wav
```

But even though the word Exception occurs in flex  Log File during tail , but it is not playing the sound .

Please let me know if there is any mistake in the above command .

I am using centOS 8 as OS and script is bash .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will find all words with Exception and replace it with the bell character, your terminal should beep/flash/whatever you've set up to happen during a terminal bell.

```
tail -f flex.log | grep "Exception" | sed -e $'s/Exception/Exception\a/'
```

To see ALL lines of `flex.log` but bell only on "Exception":

```
tail -f flex.log | sed -e $'s/Exception/Exception\a/'
```

Comment: Thanks i tried both , but none of them produced any sound . I am using centOS

Comment: Wow. You made our life easy.... Can you play a custom sound?